# Xamarin Android Dismiss ProgressDialog in async function

Tags: android, xamarin, async-await, progressdialog

I have a async function in which i want to dismiss ProgressDialog after task completes. I see it is done in onPostExecute method, however i don't have the async class to implement it. In my case it is the async method

```
    public async void ScanBarcode()
    {
        dialogIndicator.Show ();

        var zscanner = new MobileBarcodeScanner();
        //var result = await zscanner.Scan();

        var result = await zscanner.Scan ();

        HandleScanResult(result);


    }
    void HandleScanResult(ZXing.Result result)
    {
       dialogIndicator.Dismiss ();
    }
```

App throws an exception for dialogIndicator.Dismiss ();. I get

```
  "Android.Util.AndroidRuntimeException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

  at --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only    the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
  at at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:7155)
  at at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doDie(ViewRootImpl.java:6255)
  at at android.view.ViewRootImpl.die(ViewRootImpl.java:6240)
  at at    android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:365)
  at at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:320)
  at at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate(WindowManagerImpl.java:84)
  at at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:420)
  at at android.app.Dialog$1.run(Dialog.java:128)
  at at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
  at at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
  at at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5731)
  at at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
  at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
  at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
```

at at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

How to dismiss the ProgressDialog in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful to know what type of exception is thrown to see what is going wrong.

Never the less I would recommend to change some things on your code.

First it is not best practice to use `async` with the `void` return type. Because this makes it impossible to await `ScanBarcode` or catch any exceptions from there.

The second thing is that you are not doing anything inside `HandleScanResult` that couldn't be done inside `ScanBarcode`. So I would consolidate that into the following:

```
public async Task ScanBarcode()
{
    dialogIndicator.Show ();

    var zscanner = new MobileBarcodeScanner();
    var result = await zscanner.Scan ();

    dialogIndicator.Dismiss ();
}
```

This way the codes "waits" for the scan result and will then proceed with the dismissing of the dialogIndicator.

If you call `ScanBarcode` from another thread than the UI-thread you can enforce the execution on the UI-thread like this:

```
public async Task ScanBarcode()
{
    RunOnUiThread(()=>
    {
        dialogIndicator.Show ();
    });

    var zscanner = new MobileBarcodeScanner();
    var result = await zscanner.Scan ();

    RunOnUiThread(()=>
    {
        dialogIndicator.Dismiss ();
    });
}
```

Comment: I have some code in the HandleScanResult function. It is just i haven't posted it here. The actual error i get is "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."

Comment: I added code to ensure that dismiss and show is called on UI-thread.